# FormView Data Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have for fields in my datasource that I want to combine and display in one label field.  I have added a procedure to capture the databinding action but I don't how to get the data out of the datasource. I am displaying this information on a FormView is that makes anly difference.  Can I get an example in c#?

For example -

```
protected void DisplayPayOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label Payout = FormView1.FindControl("PayoutLabel") as Label;
    Payout.Text = datasource.field1 + datasource.field2;
}
```

Comment: does the code you have currently produce any results Error's ect..?

Comment: that is just sample code .. the actual data source is SqlDataSource and the two fields from the query are "wire" and "ach".  The result I want is to have the label field = wire ach

Comment: ok let me rephrase.. do you have code that will allow you to execute the query against the datasource.. from what you have why not assing var splitText = datasource.field1.ToString() + " " + datasource2.ToString(); and see what the results of splitText string variable is.. other than that it's hard to really tell what you are needing without seeing some actual written code that you have tried..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not fully sure but it seems like you're looking for something like the following:

```
protected void DisplayPayOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label Payout = FormView1.FindControl("PayoutLabel") as Label;
    object dataItem = DataBinder.GetDataItem(FormView1);
    Payout.Text = DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "field1NameHere").ToString() + DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "field2Namehere").ToString();
}
```